# socketio client fails to load

Tags: python-2.7, flask, websocket

im currently building a flask application which uses websockets. For this i would like to use the flask-socketio library. I have copied the client example as [per the docs instructions](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('hello', {data: 'Hello there!'});
    });
</script>
```

and a simple server side handler:

```
@socketio.on('hello')
def handle_hello(message):
    print message
```

however i get the following error in the borwserwindow console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read the property 'onClose' of null.
```

Anybody know what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

thats cuz you're fetching the wrong javascipt file for socket.io in your client app.
change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.6/socket.io.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem.
The reason is not compatible with python module.
You can try to install these versions.

gevent-1.1b1
greenlet-0.4.9
Flask-SocketIO-0.6.0

It's workd for me.

Comment: By the way, sockjs-1.1.0 have some problem.  You can use sockjs-1.0.3 or sockjs-1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, when i change version from 0.9.16 to 1.3.6 it worked for me.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```